# Replacing token RANDOM with a random number between 0 and 100 in a list scheme

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

#### Background

I have this current program in scheme

```lisp
(define (tsar subj srch repl)
   (cond
         ((list? subj)
          (map
              (lambda (lst) (tsar lst srch repl))
              subj))
         (else
              (if (equal? subj repl)
                   srch
                   subj))))
```

This function takes a subject `subj` as a parameter (generally speaking this is should be a list), a value to search for in the list `srch` and a value to replace the value with `repl`

Now generally, this function works:

for instance:

`(display(tsar '(1 2 () 4 (7 (7 (3 7)))) '() 3))`

yields

`(1 2 () 4 (7 (7 (() 7))))`

the atom `3` in the list is replaced with `()` as expected.

#### The problem

There's another twist to this program that I need to resolve, in situations where the atom `RANDOM` is contained in the list we need to replace that atom with a random number between 0-100 by using `(random 100)`.

#### What I know (or think I know)

I know I should probably use `eq?` or something similar to determine whether an atom is RANDOM or not. I also know (perhaps) that I can probably recursively use the `tsar` function to achieve this by passing in the list as `subj`, `RANDOM` as `srch` and `(random 100)` as `repl`.

I'm having an absolute doozy trying to wrap my head around how to make this happen (I am almost completely new to scheme and functional programming in general)

For clarification purposes RANDOM is not a string it is a symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is you have `srch` and `repl` backwards: do you really want to replace `repl` by `srch`?  You are also using `cond` in a non-idiomatic way: you don't need to write

```
(cond
  ...
  (else (if x y z)))
```

Because the body of `cond` itself is a bunch of conditionals and results, so you can just turn that into

```
(cond
  ...
  (x y)
  (else z))
```

So here is your function with those things changed (this is Racket you may need to change `[...]` to `(...)` and `λ` to `lambda`):

```
(define (tsar subj srch repl)
   (cond
     [(list? subj)
      (map (λ (lst) (tsar lst srch repl)) subj)]
     [(equal? subj srch)
      repl]
     [else subj]))
```

Now, OK to fix this to check for `RANDOM` we need another clause in the `cond` which checks for `RANDOM`.  I'm not going to write it but its test will be `(eqv? subj 'RANDOM)` and the result will be, probably `(random 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could test for that specific symbol by quoting, then return either the result of (random 100) -- assuming (random 100) returns a result between 0 and 100 in your scheme, this is apparantly not standard -- or else the subject again:

```
(if (eq? subj 'random)
    (random 100)
    subj))
```

And you would put this (eq? subj 'RANDOM) as a clause in your function's COND statement:

```
(define (tsar subj srch repl)
   (cond
         ((list? subj)
          (map
              (lambda (lst) (tsar lst srch repl))
               subj))
         ((eq? subj 'random)
               (random 100))
         (else
              (if (equal? subj repl)
                   srch
                   subj))))
```

(edited out an extraneous 'if' condition.)

As an aside: at least the Scheme I tested on, BiwaScheme, has caps-specific symbols, so 'random, 'Random, 'RANDOM, etc. all test false with each other, and you would need a COND clause for each symbol. I'm not sure how to combine them to the general case.

Comment: So I feel like this is close to what I am looking for now, the behavior I am looking for is regardless of the value of `repl` and `srch` if there is a value `RANDOM` (we are only looking for all-caps in the list) then that value needs replaces, by placing it in the conditional if it hits a RANDOM it replaces with a random number and leaves the condition which isn't quite what I'm looking for

Comment: What do you mean? This will only replace the specific instance of 'RANDOM with (random 100), but it will keep checking the other elements for srch and repl (thanks to the (map ...) recursion.

Comment: Ah, also I was fooled a bit -- (random) is apparently not standard across different scheme implementations, so the actual generation of the random number will need to work for your scheme. Editing above to make that clear.

Comment: random will work with out compiler just fine it'll compile, I'm trying what you've put and doing `(display(tsar('(1 2 'RANDOM 4) 3 4)))` but I am getting this error:
`ERROR: Wrong type to apply: (1 2 (quote RANDOM) 4)`

Comment: Ah, got it -- the 'If' was indeed short-circuiting the else clause (because *all* elements were either equal or not equal to 'RANDOM). (eq? subj 'RANDOM) should be a COND clause directly. Editing the above to be correct.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir/maam could you add a comment below when edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237655/discussion-between-halbert-and-banani720).

Answer (score 0):

Tested it using `mit-scheme`:

> 1 ]=> (fold-right  (lambda (x a) (if (eq? x 'random) (cons (random
> 100) a) (cons x a))) '() '(1 2 3))
>
> ;Value: (1 2 3)
>
> 1 ]=> (fold-right  (lambda (x a) (if (eq? x 'random) (cons (random
> 100) a) (cons x a))) '() '(1 random 3))
>
> ;Value: (1 38 3)
>
> 1 ]=> (fold-right  (lambda (x a) (if (eq? x 'random) (cons (random
> 100) a) (cons x a))) '() '(1 random random))
>
> ;Value: (1 97 50)

So you can do something like:

```
(define (doit input)
  (fold-right
    (lambda (x a)
      (if (eq? x 'random)
          (cons (random 100) a)
          (cons x a)))
    '()
    input)
```